# Castle Windsor IoC attempting to resolve CSS files (amongst others)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == null)
    {
          throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
    }
    return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
}
```

After having used Castle.Windsor as my IoC solution for a number of months, it has started this morning to throw some strange errors.

The snippet above is where my controllers get resolved against the container, but all of a suddent the ControllerFactory (where this method resides) is being hit for instances of Content and Scripts, such as:

"The controller for path '/Content/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png' could not be found."

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with custom controller factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974700/problem-with-custom-controller-factory)

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer - it is not a duplicate. These are two different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have registered the following IgnoreRoute:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx for more details.

It is added by default in new MVC3 projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found that I included css this way in **~/Content/styles**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/jquery-ui.css")" />
```

But it should be in here **~/Content/themes/base**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" />
```

Of course I had to move the file itself to the proper folder.

**Solution:**
Therefore, in my case location of the jquery*.css file was in the wrong folder. Moving it into Content/themes/base and changin css reference did the trick.